# Macro-Enabled workbook running slow/ Crashing

Tags: excel, vba

I have been creating a tool in excel that is based around data entry by a user from a userform. This entire program and the transformations done through vba span approximately 950 lines of code. Addionally, I have several power queries built to generate live-updating stats as new data is entered. The file as a whole is 64,597 KB. Currently, when I open the file it takes a descent amount of time to open with some "Excel not responding" errors before resuming the opening process. I am nervous that once I roll out this program to the users that it may "break." I am still fairly new to programming and don't have much formal training for best practices, so any tips for improving the speed/efficiency would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to tell why your workbook is so slow in opening without understanding more specifically what the code is doing and reviewing the code. Since the code is working, you can consider posting it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba+or+excel) for specific help

Comment: I will take that into consideration, Thanks! I figured it would be sort of a general question which may be hard to see without posting the code, but I appreciate the feedback!